# SQL Server 2008 R2 old version of stored procedure comes back

Tags: stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a stored procedure in my production environment that was originally written by someone that didn't have enough time to design it correctly. It was written with 9 or more joins to a database across a linked server connection.

The stored procedure was taking more than an hour to run. About a year and a half ago I redesigned it (designed it?) to access the data more efficiently and now the stored procedure only makes 2 distinct calls across the linked server. Run time dropped to less than 5 minutes after these changes.

About 6 months later (and the day after a prod release) the stored procedure performance is back to more than an hour to run. When I look at the stored procedure (right click, modify) the code has reverted the old crappy code.

No one with access to run an `ALTER PROCEDURE` would admit to having changed it, so I did what any rational trusting DBA would do - I fixed it again and put a DDL audit trigger on the production databases to track any and all DDL changes on production.

About 6 months later the crappy code is back, day after a prod release. A check of the DDL audit table shows nothing touched the stored procedure. I fixed the stored procedure and the fix event shows up in the DDL audit table.  W.T.H.??

We build our db release scripts by using Visual Studio to do a schema compare between beta and prod and then generate a script. Part of the script that is generated is several

```
EXECUTE sp_refreshsqlmodule N'[dbo].[db object here]';
```

calls. For the next few releases I make sure that no `sp_refreshsqlmodule` for the offending stored procedure are executed - and we have no issues. Then I'm out for a release and the backup DBA didn't remove the `sp_refreshsqlmodule` calls - bad code returns with no DDL audit records.

Our production server has been hard booted a few times with the correct code in place. Where / how / what is `sp_refreshsqlmodule` doing to get an old copy of the stored procedure and lay it over the good copy? How do I force the good version of the stored procedure into this magic hiding place?

Comment: I've been able to replicate this error on SQL 2008 R2 - latest patch at time of writing 10.50.6560.0 I've also confirmed that it's working OK on SQL Server 2012 SP4, although I've not been able to find out exactly when this was fixed. Upshot would be to avoid using sp_refreshsqlmodule on 2008 R2.

Answer (score 0):

I've never had this problem myself, but I have heard of somebody who had this issue when they modified the Stored Procedure in question using an ALTER command (as used by modify). When they did a DROP and CREATE instead, the issue went away.

Comment: I'll try the drop and recreate.  Thanks for the idea.

Comment: For completeness sake, this idea didn't work. Drop / Create or Alter return the same results.  We have taken to not using the sp_refreshsqlmodule any longer.

Answer (score 0):

You may have hit a bug with sp_refreshsqlmodule

The Microsoft connect link is broken so am sharing the Google cached link

https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:CaAxFpjQzjoJ:https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/656863/sp-refreshsqlmodule-corrupts-renamed-objects-definition+&cd=3&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us